# Carboy not thoroughly rinsed after cleaning with b-brite

Tags: fermentation, wine

I cleaned my wine carboy with b-brite but may not have thoroughly rinsed it. Will my wine still ferment and will it be safe to drink?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first half of your question is, "Yes." It will still ferment if there was *some* residual b-brite left in.

The answer to the second half is, "Probably..." The safety data sheet for b-brite states:

**Ingestion:** 
Short Term Exposure: Significant oral exposure is considered to be unlikely. However, this product may be irritating to mucous membranes but is unlikely to cause anything more than transient discomfort. Long Term Exposure:No data for health effects associated with long term ingestion.

**Carcinogen Status:**

**SWA:** No significant ingredient is classified as carcinogenic by SWA.

**NTP:** No significant ingredient is classified as carcinogenic by NTP.

**IARC:** No significant ingredient is classified as carcinogenic by IARC.

However, I wouldn't stake my name as a home-brewer and wine maker on failure to rinse my carboy thoroughly and potentially making people sick. It could also produce off flavoring.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much of this stuff got into your wine. Pretty impossible to guess, but it is a slow working, pretty weak stuff, so your chances are pretty good. Only way to know for sure is to wait.

It shouldn't affect safety of the drink if it will ferment, but if there is much of it, it may affect the taste.

Comment: I know the bottom of the carboy was rinsed. I normally put about a gallon of fresh water in the carboy to rinse it and flush it out through the spigot at the bottom. However, I usually rinse the sides of the carboy with the spray wand at the sink. This is the step I left out. There may have been  some of the b-brite left on the inner sides.

Comment: @ColenThomas if sides was not rinsed *at all*,  do not drink it. To the drain with it. There is difference between *not thoroughly* and *not*. You can get away with lousy job, but not with skipping it altogether.